# Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models

Tags: r

I am trying to investigate my model with R with machine learning. Training model in general works not well.

```
# # Logistic regression multiclass
for (i in 1:30) {
  # split data into training/test 
  trainPhyIndex <- createDataPartition(subs_phy$Methane, p=10/17,list =  FALSE)
  trainingPhy <- subs_phy[trainPhyIndex,]
  testingPhy <- subs_phy[-trainPhyIndex,]
  # Pre-process predictor values

  trainXphy <- trainingPhy[,names(trainingPhy)!= "Methane"]
  preProcValuesPhy <- preProcess(x= trainXphy,method = c("center","scale"))

  # using boot to avoid over-fitting
  fitControlPhyGLMNET <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 4,
                           savePredictions="final",
                           classProbs = TRUE
                           )

  fit_glmnet_phy <- train (Methane~.,
                           trainingPhy,
                           method = "glmnet", 
                           tuneGrid = expand.grid(
                             .alpha =0.1,
                             .lambda = 0.00023),
                           metric = "Accuracy",
                           trControl = fitControlPhyGLMNET)
  pred_glmnet_phy <- predict(fit_glmnet_phy, testingPhy)


  # Get the confusion matrix to see accuracy value

  u <- union(pred_glmnet_phy,testingPhy$Methane)
  t <- table(factor(pred_glmnet_phy, u), factor(testingPhy$Methane, u))
  accu_glmnet_phy <- confusionMatrix(t)
#   accu_glmnet_phy<-confusionMatrix(pred_glmnet_phy,testingPhy$Methane) 

glmnetstatsPhy[(nrow(glmnetstatsPhy)+1),] = accu_glmnet_phy$overall

}
glmnetstatsPhy
```

The program always stopped on  fit_glmnet_phy <- train (Methane~., ..
this command and shows

```
Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models
```

I have no idea about this error
I also attached the type of mathane
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T75HC.png)

Comment: That error likely means your target variable is numeric, causing `glmnet()` to run a regression model while you have the metric set to 'Accuracy' which does not apply to regressions. 'Accuracy' is a metric for classification models. What type of variable are you expecting 'Methane' to be? Is it continuous or is it a factor? Based on your desire for a confusion matrix I assume you wish for it to be a factor variable so that `glment()` produces a classification (logistic regression) algorithm.

Comment: thanks! the type of variable is float. Is that the main reason cause the error? And is there any way to fix it? i am really appreciated.

Comment: If you are predicting numeric (float) `glment()` uses regression not classification, therefore you will not be able to create a confusion matrix. What does Methane represent? Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Did you make methane binary? That is give it some form of intervals and turn it into a kind of "factor" variable.

Comment: the Methane means the production of methane. I want to use result of community analysis to predict the methane production by machine learning. I've update a figure about my data. Thanks!

Comment: Methane is a numeric value, which means you should be using regression not classification. However, you are asking for 'Accuracy' as the metric and are trying to create a confusion matrix, which indicates you are expecting a classification problem. If you wish to run a regression, you can remove the `metric='Accuracy'` argument and `train()` will choose the appropriate metric. If you are looking to create a classification algorithm you must first convert 'Methane' to a binary or categorical variable.

Comment: Got it. I am trying to create a classification and converting Methane to a binary. Thank you very much. I also try `RMSE` to instead `Accuracy`. Is there any function or command would helpful on evaluate the algorithm. I mean we can use `confusionMatrix` to evaluate the algorithm with  `metric='Accuracy'`. And I wonder is there any function I can use to evaluate the algorithm with `metric='RMSE'`?

Answer (score 3):

Try normalizing the input columns and mapping the output column as factors. This helped me resolve an issue similar to it.